# What is the world's widest pepper variety?

Tags: vegetables, peppers, fruits, variety-selection

What is the world's widest pepper variety (including both hot and sweet peppers)? The weight and length aren't in question. Just the width at any point of the pepper (it need not be uniformly wide all along the length). If it's a kind of bell pepper, please specify the variety of bell pepper (instead of just saying bell peppers).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that there is one widest variety, many of the wider varieties (like colossal, super heavyweight, etc, etc) are so similar in size, the conditions they are grown in has more to do with the potential shoulder width, than the variety does.

It would be a bell pepper, but again, I don't think one variety could be called 'widest'. Now I have never seen this, but the widest I think a pepper could get would be if it was [fasciated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasciation), which would make it go into a wide fan shape. Again, I've never seen this, but that would probably set the record.